# Geometric sum of recurrence relation

Tags: computer-science, recursive-algorithms

I am reading the textbook Algorithm Design by Kleignberg and Tardos and I am having trouble on page 216.

$$T(n) \le \sum_{j=0}^{log_2n - 1} \left ( \frac{q}{2}\right )^j  cn = cn \sum_{j=0}^{log_2n - 1} \left ( \frac{q}{2}\right )^j where \,\,\, q > 2$$

Let $r = q/2$, and since the above is a geometric series where $r > 1$ we get the formula below:

$$T(n) \le cn \left (\frac{r^{log_2n} -1}{r - 1} \right) \le cn \left( \frac{r^{log_2n}}{r - 1}\right)$$

I simply do not understand how they got the formula using the geometric series formula. In wikipedia, all the formulas for geoemtric sums have $ 1 - r$ in the denominator but this formula has $r - 1$

After a brief search here I came across this formula for finite geometric series where $r > 1$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} r^i = \frac{r^{n+1} -1}{r -1}$$

What is the name of the above formula and how come it is so hard to find it online...?

Comment: Multiply both top and bottom by $-1$ on the Wiki geometric series

Comment: The last result is a finite geometric series. It's proven in the same manner as the infinite case.

Answer (score 1):

I know it as "geometric series", but if you can't find it next time, just derive it.

$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^i &= \frac{1}{1 - x} \sum\limits_{i=0}^n (x^i - x^{i+1}) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-x} (1 - x + x - x^2 + x^2 - x^3 + x^3 - \cdots -x^n + x^n - x^{n+1}) \\
&= \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1 - x} = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1}
\end{align}
$$